# CSS - Fading All Edges of div to Transparent over Defined Distance

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a div with a solid background that contains a form. I have padding set at 50px all around this form and would like to fade out that solid colour to a transparent to see the background behind based on a pixel variable. For instance, if I wanted everything from the form to the div edge fading out, I could choose 50px. Or 45. Or 25 etc.

Current div:

[image]

What I'd like it to look like:

[image]

This div is a variable size (height: auto;) so it's not possible to just have an image as the background unfortunately.

I have tried on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc5s3gtn/31/) to fix it with linear gradients, but I have no experience with them and I think I've just cancelled everything out.

HTML:

```
<div class="formBackground">
  <form id="gform" method="POST" action="***">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
    <input type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here..." style="width: 100%; float: left;">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.formBackground {
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
  background-image : linear-gradient(to bottom, 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 0), 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 1) 90%);
  background-image : linear-gradient(to left, 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 0), 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 1) 90%);
  background-image : linear-gradient(to top, 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 0), 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 1) 90%);
  background-image : linear-gradient(to right, 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 0), 
                    rgba(55,54,51, 1) 90%);
  padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 4.5em;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used box shadows in the past to achieve this sort of effect.

```
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px rgba(55,54,51, 1);
```

By adding a box shadow with a translation of 0px in any direction, a spread distance of 25px, and a blur radius of 25px, it makes it the 50px blur you like. By changing the margin to 50px and using `top`, `right`, etc. for positioning you can get it exactly where you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="formBackground">
  <form id="gform" method="POST" action="***">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
    <input type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here..." style="width: 100%; float: left;">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.formBackground {
    height: auto;
    background-color : rgba(55,54,51, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px rgba(55,54,51, 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will cause issues in IE11 at certain resolutions.

Answer (score 4):

You should combine all the gradient in the same background. You need to also rely on some radial-gradient for the corner.

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
  /*center*/
  linear-gradient(rgba(55, 54, 51, 1),rgba(55, 54, 51, 1)) center/calc(100% - 40px) calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat,
  /*4 corners*/
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, rgba(55, 54, 51, 1) , rgba(55, 54, 51, 0) 70%) top right /20px 20px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, rgba(55, 54, 51, 1) , rgba(55, 54, 51, 0) 70%) top left /20px 20px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgba(55, 54, 51, 1) , rgba(55, 54, 51, 0) 70%) bottom left /20px 20px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at top left, rgba(55, 54, 51, 1) , rgba(55, 54, 51, 0) 70%) bottom right /20px 20px no-repeat,
  /*4 sides*/
  linear-gradient(to left, rgba(55, 54, 51, 0), rgba(55, 54, 51, 1)) right center/20px calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(55, 54, 51, 0), rgba(55, 54, 51, 1)) left center/20px calc(100% - 40px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(55, 54, 51, 0), rgba(55, 54, 51, 1)) top center/calc(100% - 40px)  20px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to top, rgba(55, 54, 51, 0), rgba(55, 54, 51, 1)) bottom center/calc(100% - 40px)  20px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:500px;">
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:200px;">
</div>
```

Here is another syntax with CSS variables where you can easily adjust the colors and distance:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#fff;
  --i:55, 54, 51;
  --c:rgba(var(--i),1) , rgba(var(--i), 0);
  --d:20px;
  padding:var(--d);
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(rgba(var(--i), 1),rgba(var(--i), 1)),
  
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, var(--c)  70%),
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, var(--c) 70%),
  radial-gradient(circle at top right, var(--c) 70%),
  radial-gradient(circle at top left, var(--c) 70%),
  
  linear-gradient(to right, var(--c)),
  linear-gradient(to left, var(--c)),
  linear-gradient(to top, var(--c)),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--c));
  
  background-size:
   calc(100% - 2*var(--d)) calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),
   
   var(--d) var(--d),var(--d) var(--d),var(--d) var(--d),var(--d) var(--d),
   
   var(--d) calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),var(--d) calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),calc(100% - 2*var(--d)) var(--d),calc(100% - 2*var(--d)) var(--d);
  background-position:center,
  
    top right,top left,bottom left,bottom right,
    
    right center, left center,top center, bottom center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some content
</div>

<div class="box" style="--d:40px;--i:0,20,70">
Some content
</div>


<div class="box" style="--d:10px;--i:255,0,0">
Some content
</div>
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on IE11 while responsiveness and transparency were at play. Excellent.